# size of array function parameter will return char*

Tags: c, char, sizeof, fgets

I wanted to store a string with spaces and the print it. As I want to store spaces I´m using fgets(), right after I remove from the char array the '\n' that I type when introducing the text.
And it works well but I wanted to pack those two statements in a function called xcan(), and here comes the troubles, I try to compile it but I get a warning and a note. but I dont know what do they mean:
in line 4: warning: 'sizeof' on array function parameter 'a' will return size of 'char *'
in line 3 note: declared here void xcan(char a[50])

The weird part is that it compiles and it wors but it only prints the first 6 characters thath I introduce

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
/*void xcan(char a[50]){    
    fgets(a, sizeof(a), stdin);

    a[strlen(a)-1] = '\0';
}*/

int main(){
    char full_Name[50]; 

    printf("Your name, your name: ");
    
    fgets(full_Name, sizeof(full_Name), stdin);
    full_Name[strlen(full_Name)-1] = '\0';
    
    //xcan(full_Name);
    
    printf("%s", full_Name);
}
```

My guessing is that it passes 6 to the fgets() second parameter. So size of char * is 6 but I don't understand what it means.
As you can see I'm kind of a noob.. anyways thank you guys for reading this

Comment: `void xcan(char a[50]){` is `void xcan(char *a){` - arrays decay to pointers in function parameters

Comment: To paraphrase Reagan: "Don't guess; verify"

Comment: `int foo(char a[50]) { ... }` is 100% equivalent to `int foo(char *a) { ... }` and that means `a` (inside the function) is a pointer. `sizeof a` yields the size of the pointer, not the size of the underlying array. If you do not pass the array size from the calling function, `foo()` has no way to know the original size.

Comment: The simplest way is simply to pass the array size as a `size_t` argument to your `xcan` function.

Comment: Also note that after `fgets`, the assignment `a[strlen(a)-1] = '\0'` is flawed. First of all you don't even check if [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) succeeded or not; Secondly see [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input) for a much safer way (if `fgets` succeeds of course).